# Preserve all backslashes in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string containing backslashes:

```
"{ \time 4/4 \key c \major d'4 }"
```

When I try to pass it in a nodejs child_process or just to console.log it, 
the backslashes are removed:

```
console.log("{ \time 4/4 \key c \major d'4 }");   
// "{   ime 4/4 key c major d'4 }"
```

I have tried all things I cound find, such as `.replace(/\\/g, '\\')` or `JSON.stringify`, but nothing seems to work.

The string is constructed dynamically so I can't escape it manually.

Any ideas?

---

Update after comments:

I am getting this string from a library written in python ([python-mingus](https://github.com/bspaans/python-mingus)) using [node-python](https://github.com/electronifie/node-python).

As I understand from the answers and the comments, there is no way to parse the string correctly without altering either the library or the wrapper...

Thank you all.

Comment: `"{ \\time 4/4 \\key c \\major d'4 }"` works fine. You need to escape *before* you put your data into javascript. Where are you getting it from?

Comment: "constructed dynamically" how exactly, and why are the slashes there? If it's a string literal the slashes are probably being removed by the parser.

Comment: The two-character string literal `\m` only expresses a one-character string value. JavaScript can only act on string values, not string literals. You might as well ask to preserve the `e` in the numeric literal `10e2`. You can't; that literal expresses the value `1000` and the value doesn't have an `e`. Similarly, the literal `\m` expresses the value `m` and the value doesn't have a backslash.

Comment: You cannot fix the string if the literal is incorrect. The slashes are treated as escape sequences and are already discarded by the time it's a value in memory. You'll have to fix the "dynamic construction."

Comment: Hopefully the backslashes are not important because they are gone by the time the javascript parser digests them.

Comment: JSON.stringify(str) will turn a string into a literal. perfectly.

Comment: @dandavis, not perfectly, it keeps `\t` but strips the unrecognized sequences (`\k`, `\m`)

Comment: @mutil: JSON.stringify should turn "\k" into "\\k", unless you really fed it just "k". if that's the case, you need to feed it the source of your string, be it a file, callback, etc. once you have it parsed as a string, it's too late because the extra slash has been tossed. JSON.stringfiy will accept and return a string, so it can fit in the middle of whatever process provides your strings.

Answer (score 24):

You could use String.raw as alternative to save strings containing slashes;
To his you have to put your string between grave sign (`) as follows:

```
var path = String.raw`your\string\with\slash`;
```

this way you can preserve slashes.

Comment: Most ellegant solution, and actually really the intended behaviour of `String.raw`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw : `"All kinds of escape characters will be ineffective and backslashes will be present in the output string"`

Comment: Note that these strings can't have a trailing \. You may need to handle that specially.

Comment: Actually saved my day! Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

No, your string does not contain (literal) backslashes.

`\` is an escape character, and `\t`, `\k` and `\m` are treated as escape sequences **at the time of parsing** (and not at the time of printing, as you seem to think). They never even reach your `replace` because they aren't there anymore when it runs. Also, for unrecognised sequences (`\k` and `\m`), the backslash is simply ignored.

The only way to prevent that is to add an additional backslash **in the source code**:

```
"{ \\time 4/4 \\key c \\major d'4 }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly if you type the characters `$$ \sum \theta $$` into an HTML text input box javascript will pick them up and pass them on unchanged and even console.log will print them out unchanged.

```
var TextSource = document.getElementById( "myHTMLTextInputBox" );
var labelStr = TextSource.value;
console.log ("Obtained text = ", labelStr);
```

Likewise you can type the same character sequence into the definition of an HTML DIV like this:-

```
<div id="anne" name="bob" class="carla" title ="tommy"> $$ \sum \theta $$ </div>
```

(I wonder how those processes are explained in terms of parsing?)