# How to validate the uber webhook api?

Tags: json, node.js, hmac, webhooks, uber-api

The Uber [documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/webhooks) say

> The value of this field is a hexadecimal HMAC signature of the webhook HTTP request body, using the client secret as a key and SHA256 as the hash function.

But what is the HTTP request body? I assume it is the JSON body received from the webhook (https://developer.uber.com/docs/webhooks#section-example-post).

If it is, then how to validate it in NodeJS as the crypto module for HMAC doesn't accept JSON[I've tried to stringify the JSON, but it generates a different hash]. Or how to I convert the JSON into a buffer, since that is the next best option

If not, then what should I be using?

**[UPDATE1]** Code used for the task:

```
app.post("/",function(req,res){
const crypto = require('crypto');
var input = res.body
var str_input=JSON.stringify(input)

const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', '<CLIENT SECRET>');

hmac.update(str_input);
console.log(hmac.digest('hex')); // print same as below
console.log("e034ac7db29c3c0c10dfeced41a6cd850ed74c1c3c620863d47654cc7390359a")
})
```

Comment: you are correct that `JSON.stringify(req.body)` is what you should be passing to your hashing function. Can you include the code for your hashing function in the question?

Comment: @AndrewNoonan I've added the code for the same

Comment: Please, can you post the final code? I added the answer's replace to my code as: `var input = JSON.stringify(req.body).replace(/\//g, '\\' + '/');` but this didn't work. Uber signature keeps not being equal to the header one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Uber considered the insertion of backslashes into webhook bodies a bug and released a fix. The workaround below will now break comparisons. As of 4/28/2016, clients written in Node should just perform the comparison without modifying the webhook body. Clients in languages that don't share Node's behavior of ignoring blackslashes in escape sequences are unaffected.

**Original Answer**

JS [ignores the backslash when reading escape sequences in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466581/preserve-all-backslashes-in-a-string?answertab=votes#tab-top). The missing backslash is breaking your comparison because it's included in webhook event signatures.

An immediate workaround is to re-insert those backslashes using a regex.

`var reconstitutedWebhookBody = input.replace(/\//g, '\\' + '/');`

That regex will need to be extended if webhooks ever start including other escapable characters.

Comment: First time I've come across this problem in JS. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Please, can you post the final code? I added the answer's replace to my code as: `var input = JSON.stringify(req.body).replace(/\//g, '\\' + '/');` but this didn't work. Uber signature keeps not being equal to the header one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Uber send json with spaces before keys and values. Like this

```
{"event_id": "...", "resource_href": "...", "meta": {"status": "...", "rider_id": "...", "user_id": "...", "resource_id": "..."}, "event_type": "...", "event_time": ...}
```

You can do this before activating boryparser. And create hex from this data

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

let data = "";
req.on('data', function(chunk){data += chunk});
req.on('end', function(){
    req.jsonBody = JSON.parse(data);
    req.rawBody = data;
    req.originalUberReq = data;
});
next();
});
```